# Import DNS list in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I have a bunch of DNS addresses I'd like to add to my Windows 7 installation. Since I've been getting `DNS server is not responding` messages way too often (even with Google's DNS), I figure that with an exhaustive DNS list, at least there's nothing left for me to blame. Problem is, Windows' archaic interface of adding it one at a time via

> Connection Properties > Networking > Internet Protocol Version 4 > Advanced > DNS

is painstakingly tedious, and the list may be useful for adding to other machines I use too.

Is there a better way to add DNS records, or some place where I can edit to paste a list in?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the source of your problem is actually unavailable DNS servers.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg In some countries (aka China) which DNS server you use can get you into trouble based on your web surfing habits.  Or some folks might be trying to circumnavigate their nations censor firewall.

Comment: @xiankai have you looked into scripting options, do you have any experience in scripting?

Comment: I am open to scripting, like Powershell I guess? Not exactly sure what to start searching for though.

Comment: @Colyn1337 - I must point out anyone who uses the term `painstakingly tedious` in the correct context first language must to be English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `netsh` to set your DNS setting for a network connection. For example:

```
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.8.8
netsh interface ip add dns name="Local Area Connection" addr=8.8.4.4 index=2
```

This would set `8.8.8.8` as you primary DNS service and `8.8.4.4` as your secondary server. Add as many as you need, just increase the `index` with every call.

Comment: I made a batch file and copied a line per DNS, took a bit of time (doing validation I guess?) and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @xiankai Check into "for\each" loops, they make that manual process a bit easier ;)

Comment: @Colyn1337 ooh, great tip!

Answer (score -1):

As Oliver said, your problem is probably caused by something other than your DNS servers.

You can get a clearer view of things by using NSLookup, since it skips the local DNS cache and hosts file.

If you get bad results with NSLookup, you should try running a query through some online service like [this one](http://ping.eu/nslookup/) or [this one](http://serversniff.net/index.php), or even connect through VPN and then try DNS queries.
This is probably enough to disqualify the censorship option.

I don't think that adding multiple DNS servers is the solution, but a temporary one.